# What is a proper way to load data into a form with comboboxes?

Tags: extjs, combobox, sencha-touch

Sencha recommends to avoid manual loading of data into a form and use `loadRecord` instead. But if there are combos in the form, what happens is that `valueField` is inserted into the text area, instead of `displayField`. One would think that the associated store should be loaded first and then the `loadRecord` has to be invoked. But what is the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadRecord` is a very simple function that takes values from the record fields and then calls `setValue(recordFieldValue)` on the corresponding form fields (where name of the record field matches name of the form field).

Hence, if the form field combo store is not loaded, or if `recordFieldValue` is not found in the store, then the raw value is just displayed in the text part of the combo.

You must assure that the combo store is loaded before you call load record.

Comment: That's exactly what I do, but it seems to be a bit too primitive. I haven't tried but maybe if the record contains both - valueField and displayField then loadRecord will display it properly?

Comment: It's all about calling `combo.setValue(recordFieldValue)`. Combo has store with value/text pairs so if `recordFieldValue` does not match any record in the store then value, not text, is displayed in the combo.

Comment: I ended up writing my own variation.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the key "name" to each form field to have it working.
Then you can add either a record to be loaded or to add data.

```
intialize: function() {
    var data = {
        nameOfComboItem: false, // validValue
        nameOfSecondComboItem: true
    };
    this.down('formpanel').setData(data);
}
```

Comment: It's a form, of course I have names on the fields. Or what you mean?

Comment: I've reread my question and apparently it was a bit ambiguous. So I clarified it a bit.